# documentFilter IntFilter not filtering first two characters on first run

Tags: java, documentfilter

I have an IntFilter that will filter the characters inputted to be only integer, on the every first run of the program it will not be able to filter 1 or 2 non-integer characters but after that it will only allow integer inputs. I found this code online and combined it with a size filter, even before combining the two it was still unable to filter the first inputs only after a time will the text input be filtered.

Can anyone help me isolate the problem here why is it that it cannot filter the first inputted characters.

Here is the event function:

```
private void amountKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
        ((AbstractDocument) amount.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new IntFilter(5));
    }
```

The documentFilter:

```
public class IntFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        private int maxCharacters;    

        public IntFilter(int maxChars) {
            maxCharacters = maxChars;
        }

        @Override
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                                    String string, AttributeSet attr)
                   throws BadLocationException {
            char ch;     
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(string);
            for (int i = buffer.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                ch = buffer.charAt(i);
                if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                    buffer.deleteCharAt(i);
                }
            }
            if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + string.length()) <= maxCharacters){
                 super.insertString(fb, offset, buffer.toString(), attr);
            }
        }

        @Override
       public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
            int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            if (length > 0){
               fb.remove(offset, length);
            }
            insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
       }
    }
```